# Cyclic barrier await method not working

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to learn multithreading and was trying with a cyclic barrier. I understand that to break the barrier an await method must be called by the number of the thread mentioned while creating the barrier. I am trying to do the same but when I check if the barrier is broke my main method is going in an infinite loop.

```
class CyclicBarrierTrial implements Runnable{

    CyclicBarrier barrier;
    public CyclicBarrierTrial(CyclicBarrier barrier){
        this.barrier=barrier;
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("in the run method");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("going to call awake on barrier"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                barrier.await();
            } catch (BrokenBarrierException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("barrier broke");

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println("Wake up from the Sleep"+ Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MYCountDownLatch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

        Thread t1= new Thread(new CyclicBarrierTrial((barrier)));
        t1.start();
        Thread t2= new Thread(new CyclicBarrierTrial((barrier)));
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        t2.start();
        while(!barrier.isBroken())
        {
            System.out.println("waiting for the barrier to break "+barrier.isBroken());
        }

        System.out.println("MAIN THREAD  finally barrier to broke ");

    }
}
```

Comment: `I understand that to break the barrier an await method must be called by the number of the thread mentioned while creating the barrier.` - No, this is a way for *bypass* a barrier. "Broken" barrier is some another thing, see documentation about [.isBroken](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#isBroken()) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

barrier.isBroken() indicates if barrier is in broken state, which is different than barrier is tripper.

To check this, you can try interrupting one of thread, this will raise BarrierBrokenException on other threads and barrier.isBroken() will be true.

```
  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

If you want to wait for all threads to complete, then you can use [ExecutorService.awaitTermination](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) or [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html)

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html): 
If any thread is interrupted while waiting, then all other waiting threads will throw BrokenBarrierException and the barrier is placed in the broken state.

Hope this help.